# How to get the last occurrence of a word from a list of possible words using Javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to test if an address contains a particular placename from a list of placenames. For example, if I have an address that looks like `123 someplace, someStreet, dublin` then the following regex `(dublin|cork|galway)` will give me county `dublin`.

The problem is if `dublin` was to appear in some other portion of the address e.g. `123 someplace, dublin road, cork` then I'll still get `dublin` but I actually want `cork`.

Is it possible to write a regex to get the last occurrence, if any, of a list of possible match words. I see that C# regexes have a right-to-left option, that would be great but I don't think Javascript has anything like that, does it?

Note that I can't rely on the formatting of the address, so there might not be commas delimiting the string. Also, although it is very likely that the word I'm looking for is the very last word in the string, this might not always be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positive look ahead

```
(dublin|cork|galway)(?!.*(dublin|cork|galway))
```

matches the last occurence

see how the regex works

http://regex101.com/r/yQ6bY1/2

`(?!.*(dublin|cork|galway))` asserts that the pattern cannot be matched after the presceding pattern, (dublin|cork|galway)

OR

To be more precise,

```
\b(dublin|cork|galway)\b(?!.*\b(dublin|cork|galway)\b)
```

Thanks to  nhahtdh for the suggestion.

Comment: No word boundary check?

Answer (score 2):

Find desired string and check that end of line does not contain it.

```
(dublin|cork|galway)(?!.*(dublin|cork|galway))
```

[regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/xD2fC3/1)

Comment: Identical answers, sorry, had to pick one - other guy got in there first